# How can I prove Stokes theorem using Green's formula?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

$$ \int_{\partial \Omega} (u ~dx + v ~dy) = \iint_{\Omega} \left( \frac{\partial v}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} \right) ~dx ~dy $$ Then I want to prove that$$ \int_{\partial \Omega} w = \iint_{\Omega} ~dw, \;(w = u ~dx + v ~dy) $$ Would you give me an elementary proof for this?

Comment: I don't mean the implication. I want to know the proof of Stokes theorem by using Green's formula.

Comment: Technically Green's theorem and Stokes are equivalent provided you view the fact that exterior derivatives commute with pullbacks as "trivial".   The proof amounts to evaluating both sides of Stokes in a coordinate patch, where it reduces to Green's theorem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\def\d{\mathrm{d}}
\def\w{\omega}$Green's theorem is a special case of [Stokes' theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stokes%27_theorem), not the other way around.

Let $\w$ be the [differential one-form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_form) $u \d x + v \d y$. 
The [exterior derivative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_derivative) of $\w$ is 
$$\d \w = \left(\frac{\partial v}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\right)\d x\wedge \d y.$$
Stokes' theorem takes the form
$$\int_{\partial\Omega} (u \d x + v \d y) 
= \int_\Omega \left(\frac{\partial v}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\right)\d x\wedge \d y.$$
Since the manifold is $\mathbb{R}^2$ this can be rewritten as
$$\int_{\partial \Omega} (u dx + v dy) 
= \int_{\Omega} \left( \frac{\partial v}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} \right) dx dy.$$
This is Green's theorem.

Comment: +1 for : "Green's theorem is a special case of Stokes' theorem, not the other way around"!

Comment: @Ann: Hi Ann. Stokes' theorem is about integration on $n$-dimensional manifolds and their boundaries, much more general spaces than considered in Green's theorem.